# Filtering odata results based on a value contained in a navigation property

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, wcf-data-services, odata

Using the Northwind OData feed available at http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/, how would one go about getting back a list of Employees that are assigned to TerritoryID = 19713?

I can get the Employees and territories using the following LINQ query, but without the All/Any methods, I'm not sure how to do what I'm asking.

```
from e in Employees.Expand("Territories") select e
```

I'm assuming this is simple and I'm just not seeing the forest for the trees...so, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The URL doesn't work... the subdomain doesn't exist

Comment: You may want to try again...the URL works fine for me.

Comment: Still not working for me, I can't resolve the hostname. That's weird...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque No problem here either. Firewall?

Comment: @GertArnold, no... perhaps a problem with my ISP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you can turn it around

```
Territories.Expand("Employees").Where (t => t.TerritoryID == "19713")
```

But generally, linq to odata has a very restricted subset of operands. Methods like `Any` or `Contains`, which would be useful in similar queries in e.g. linq to entities, are not supported.

Comment: They just added Any/All support to OData v3 and WCF Data Services 5.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee622463(v=vs.103).aspx#filtering.  Unfortunately the Northwind svc is still version 2 so your way is the only way to go I think.

Comment: @JasonFreitas Good to know that!

Comment: There is a V3 Northwind service up there as well. For example: http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Categories?$filter=Products/any(p:p/UnitPrice gt 20)

Comment: Thanks to all of you.  I downloaded the latest WCF Data Services and after making the necessary updates to the service and the clients, I was able to do exactly what I needed using the Any/All methods.